# Error converting nvarchar to numeric.. when converting nvarchar within comma seperates to decimal

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with data as below:

| Id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 7E38AD4A-4C6E-40D9-B805-08C1F4EE14D0 | 1,370 |
| E48A0A4A-6E6C-41A8-B379-0E14452938C6 | 1,200 |
| 55FF871D-CB78-4A38-8817-154DFC723E06 | 1,124 |
| 915D7C86-71B9-4BC5-99EA-18B2FAB559FF | 1,245 |
| A80F6396-222C-4E9C-9782-298E43609586 | 1,000 |
| 55EE03CC-0825-43E8-A792-33BE5F01C594 | 1,029 |
| 51176178-7CCD-4984-82EE-342574D85742 | 1,206 |
| C2FBFD1D-469D-43FF-9D9E-3F56BE9BCF34 | 1,243 |

I want to convert the `value` column (of type `nvarchar(50)`) to `decimal(18, 2)`, but I get the following error :

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

while executing the query.

Here is my T-SQL:

```
SELECT 
    Id, 
    IIF(ISNUMERIC([Value]) = 1, CAST([Value] AS DECIMAL(18, 2)), 0) AS Value
FROM 
    [dbo].[AssetLD]
```

Please help, thanks

Comment: What "`decimal`" value is `'7E38AD4A-4C6E-40D9-B805-08C1F4EE14D0'` when it's at home?

Comment: Those are string representations of a GUID, what decimal value would you expect to see?

Comment: Also, I suggest avoiding the use of `ISNUMERIC` it gives both false positives and negatives. If you are converting values and not sure if they'll be valid, use `TRY_CONVERT`/`TRY_CAST`.

Comment: I don't know why the table was not showing the value column, I've updated what data should be there

Comment: Editing your post the data table looks correct and I agree, I can't get it to display correctly either. Assuming your comma represents a decimal point, have you tried `cast(replace([Value],',','.') AS DECIMAL(18,2))`?

Comment: @Stu yeah it's just work correctly. Thanks

Comment: Relevant: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/301632/strange-behavior-with-quotename-and-substring/301650#301650. You should use `TRY_CAST` and remove `ISNUMERIC`

Comment: It sounds like you should just strip out the commas (assuming those indicate thousands.) Casting to money might have rounding issues if you're not careful.

Comment: Is this a EAV model and that is the reason for storing numeric (and anything else!) values in a string column? Is that something that can be changed?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, conversions to `decimal` do not accept a `,` separator for thousands.

However a `money` conversion *does* accept it.

> Note that you should always use `TRY_CONVERT/CAST`, rather than `ISNUMERIC` which has many issues

```sql
SELECT 
    Id, 
    ISNULL(CAST(TRY_CONVERT(money, [Value], 1) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)), 0) AS Value
FROM 
    [dbo].[AssetLD];
```

**An even better solution** is to use `TRY_PARSE`, which will use the correct formatting for a particular culture.

For example, if `,` actually means a decimal point (for example in `de-DE` culture), you can do

```
SELECT 
    Id, 
    ISNULL(TRY_PARSE([Value] AS DECIMAL(18, 2) USING 'de-DE'), 0) AS Value
FROM 
    [dbo].[AssetLD];
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b18850d92c0d89cbdb74a4e5a320a1b7)